# if... else statement and arrays

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use an if... else statement and assign values to the variable stateCode through the values of the array elements. Something is not working maybe the array is not correct.
Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>if...else</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function choices() {
   var stateCode = document.getElementById("x").value;
   var taxes = new Array(10; 7.5; 3.2);
     if ("x" === "OR") {
     document.writeln(taxes[0]);
   } else if ("x" === "CA") {
     document.writeln(taxes[1]);
   } else if ("x" === "MO") {
     document.writeln(taxes[2]);
   }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
   <select id="x" onchange="choices(this.value);">
     <option value = "">---Reset---</option>
     <option value = "MO">MO</option>
     <option value = "OR">OR</option>
     <option value = "CA">CA</option>
   </select>

</p>       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I doubt the string `"x"` will ever equal the string `"OR"`...

Comment: Perhaps you meant to write `if ( stateCode === "OR" )` &c.

Comment: `;` is also a syntax error in `new Array(10; 7.5; 3.2)`. Those should be commas, and really, you should use array literal notation as well: `[10, 7.5, 3.2]`.

Comment: aaaaand if any of the `document.write()` calls ever execute, it's going to completely overwrite what's in the DOM. And you're passing the dropdown's value to `choices()` but ignoring that parameter in the function; why? You should really start getting familiar with your browser's developer tools, pronto.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if ("x" === "OR") {
     document.writeln(taxes[0]);
   } else if ("x" === "CA") {
     document.writeln(taxes[1]);
   } else if ("x" === "MO") {
```

Replace `"x"` with `stateCode` and try again

and replace `var taxes = new Array(10; 7.5; 3.2);` with:

```
var taxes = new Array(10, 7.5, 3.2);
```

It should work, it worked for me.

How about this then: replace your whole function with this:

```
function choices() {
    var stateCode = document.getElementById("x");
    var taxes = new Array(10, 7.5, 3.2);
    if (stateCode.value != "") {
        document.getElementById("taxes").innerHTML = taxes[stateCode.selectedIndex - 1];
    }
}
```

and add a `<div id="taxes"></div>` somewhere on the page.

Comment: And replace `new Array(10; 7.5; 3.2);` with `new Array(10, 7.5, 3.2);`

Comment: @Robin `[10, 7.5, 3.2]` is even better. It's more concise, and `new Array()`'s arguments are confusing at best.

Comment: I tryed this but it's not working yet

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure where all the hate is coming from. However, you have a slue of issues.

1. document.writeln is never good in javascript. It overwrites the document. Meaning your select box will disappear.
2. you must have a typo since your string comparison is just silly. However, good job using ===
3. inline method handlers, `onchange="choices(this.value);"`, aren't the worst thing ever. But they should be avoided. Using javascript you can handle different quirks between browsers much easier.
4. A modern browser will have a method to debug this code. Firebug for firefox, F12 (PC) in internet explorer, and the debug console in webkit browsers. These will tell you line numbers and allow you to pinpoint issues with deadly precision.
5. You are currently sending the value of the select in the inline handler so just use that i guess.
6. `new Array` syntax is troublesome. I avoid it and use bracket, `[10, 3.2, 3]`.

---

As for you question:

add HTML

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

...

```
function choices(stateCode) {
    var results = document.getElementById("results");
    var taxes = [10, 7.5, 3.2];

     switch(stateCode) {
        case "OR": 
            results.innerHTML = taxes[0];
            break;
        case "CA":
            results.innerHTML = taxes[1];
            break;
        case "MO":
            results.innerHTML = taxes[2];
            break;
        default:
            results.innerHTML = "No tax records for entry: " + stateCode;
            break;
     }
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/vF73T/)